# interpolate the circle going through three points using splines

Tags: computational-geometry, b-spline

It is known from Geometry that any 3 points determine a circle.  This is the problem of Appolonius

[image]

Programming solutions try to *approximate* using Bezier curves.  Can you not draw conics as Bezier curves?  I thought you could get an exact answer using enough control points.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229695/draw-2-bezier-curves-through-3-points-to-mimic-a-circle-arc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376749/drawing-a-circle-given-three-points [closed]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314306/find-arc-circle-equation-given-three-points-in-space-3d

I would like to be able to input the points $A,B,C$ and return the list of points on the arc $\overline{AB}$ on the circle.

---

It is possible to compute this formula exactly, such as using the determinant method (or [others](http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/circle%20given%203%20points.htm)), but here I am interested in a **spline based solution**.  This will be useful when I have many many measurements, known to fit a circle, but no one circle exactly fits all of them.

$$ \left| \begin{array}{llll} x^2 + y^2 & x & y & 1 \\ 
x_1^2 + y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2^2 + y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3^2 + y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\\end{array}\right| = 0$$

Comment: Why not make least squares fit to the radius after computing the center of mass of all your points? Is there something else driving you to want a spline?

Comment: What task do you want to solve?  Is it "Three points to circle?" and "Circle to Bezier Curves" - or, since you mention several point, are you after a "from n points to best circle" algorithm?

Comment: @BillBarth that won't work (the center won't be right) if the sample points are not uniformly distributed around the circle. A best fit to a a circle does seem like a good idea though.

Comment: @DougLipinski, good point. Searching "best fit circle" yields lots of results that look decent though if splines aren't a hard requirement.

Comment: *Rational* Bézier curves: see [this Math.StackExchange answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/450231/80812). Also [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline#Example:_a_circle). But a least-squares fit of your points to a circle sounds more like what you're looking for.

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10957/280